# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string | NextJS 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have an SSG page that looks like this:

```js
/*
imports......
*/

export default async function Page({ params: { page }, searchParams }) {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams)


    const count = await getPageCount(queryParams.toString())
    const { products, total, reached, error } = await getProducts(queryParams.toString(), parseInt(page) || 1)

    if (error || !products?.length) {
        return <Error404></Error404>
    }

    const categories = await getCategories()

    return (
        <>
            <div className={"productParent"}>
                <Filter categories={categories} searchParams={searchParams} reached={parseInt(reached)} total={parseInt(total)}></Filter>

                <div className="products">
                    {products.map(product => {
                        return <ProductCard {...product} key={product.id}></ProductCard>
                    })}
                    <Pagination count={count} initialPage={parseInt(page)} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
    const count = await getPageCount('')
    const items = new Array(count).fill(null)
    return items.map((value, index) => ({
        page: (index + 1).toString()
    }))
}
```

I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string (at 1:1:22251)`
It only happens at build (using `npm run build`) and not in dev mode. The problem resolves when I comment the `<Pagination>` component. Here is the component:

```js
'use client'
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

type Props = {
    count: number
    initialPage: number
}


export default function Pagination({ count, initialPage }: Props) {
    const pathParams = useSearchParams()    
    const isFirstRender = useRef(true)
    const maxPageLinks = 4;

    const [page, setPage] = useState(initialPage)
    const router = useRouter()

    const handleClick = (page) => {
        setPage(page);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isFirstRender.current) {
            isFirstRender.current = false
            return
        }
        const pathParamsString = pathParams.toString()
        if (pathParamsString) {
            router.push(`/page/${page}?${pathParamsString}`)
        } else {
            router.push(`/page/${page}`)
        }
    }, [page])



    const getPages = () => {
        let pages = [];
        const startPage = Math.max(page - Math.floor(maxPageLinks / 2), 1);
        const endPage = Math.min(startPage + maxPageLinks - 1, count);
        if (!pathParams)
            return []
        if (count <= 5) {
            for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                pages.push(
                    <Link
                        href={`/page/${i}${pathParams.toString() ? `?${pathParams.toString()}` : ''}`}
                        key={i}
                        className={page === i ? 'active' : ''}
                        onClick={() => handleClick(i)}
                    >
                        {i}
                    </Link>
                );
            }
        } else {
            if (startPage > 1) {
                pages.push(
                    <Link
                        href={`/page/1${pathParams.toString() ? `?${pathParams.toString()}` : ''}`}
                        key={1}
                        className={page === 1 ? 'active' : ''}
                        onClick={() => handleClick(1)}
                    >
                        1
                    </Link>
                );

                if (startPage > 2) {
                    pages.push(<div className="spread" key="spread-start">...</div>);
                }
            }

            for (let i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) {
                pages.push(
                    <Link
                        href={`/page/${i}${pathParams.toString() ? `?${pathParams.toString()}` : ''}`}
                        key={i}
                        className={page === i ? 'active' : ''}
                        onClick={() => handleClick(i)}
                    >
                        {i}
                    </Link>
                );
            }

            if (endPage < count) {
                if (endPage < count - 1) {
                    pages.push(<div className="spread" key="spread-end">...</div>);
                }

                pages.push(
                    <Link
                        href={`/page/${count}${pathParams.toString() ? `?${pathParams.toString()}` : ''}`}
                        key={count}
                        className={page === count ? 'active' : ''}
                        onClick={() => handleClick(count)}
                    >
                        {count}
                    </Link>
                );
            }
        }

        return pages;
    };

    return (
        <div className="pagination">
            <div
                className={`previous ${page === 1 ? 'disabled' : ''}`}
                onClick={() => page > 1 && handleClick(page - 1)}
            >
            </div>
            
            {getPages()}
            <div
                className={`next ${page === count ? 'disabled' : ''}`}
                onClick={() => page < count ? handleClick(page + 1) : () => { }}
            >
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem resolves when I change the `const pathParams = useSearchParams()` `const pathParams = new URLSearchParams()`

I have tried using vanilla JS instead of the `useSearchParams` hook, but it doesn't work the same way, and I've checked all the string concatenation `useSearchParams` hook is there.

Comment: @James You are referring to the documentation of `react-router-dom` I'm using `useSearchParams` from `next/navigation`

Comment: Oops, yes, I was referring to the wrong library's useSearchParams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using NextJS 13.0.2 I upgraded to 13.0.4 and the issue is gone. Still not sure what was causing this issue, highly likely that this hook was not stable in this version.